# Dropzone is not working, How can i solve this problem

Tags: javascript, html, dropzone.js

I have a webform with masterpage. Dropzone is not working . I have tried everything but i can not solve.

HTML

```
<div class="block push-up-10">
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone dropzone-mini dz-clickable"><div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div></form>
                    </div>
```

REF

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/dropzone/dropzone.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: do you get an error? anything at all?

Comment: @cloned No I can see only empty div

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" class="dropzone dropzone-mini dz clickable">
  <label class="dz-default dz-message">Drop files here to upload</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
```

You have to add input tag inside of a div.

And don't forget to add javascript

For jquery use `$("div#myId").dropzone({ url: "/file/post" });`

For vanilla JS use `new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "/file/post"});`